# Change the value of a static variable

Tags: objective-c, static-variables

How can I change the value of a static variable in Objective-C?

Is this allowed?

Comment: what is your problem `variable=newValue;` is not working?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya it just keeps the old value without error message or anything.

Comment: @findusl: Try with overriding the class and the static variable.

Comment: @anoopvaidya I need it for tests and I don't have control over the instantiation. I googled more it seems to be that you can't change static from a different file, changed it to extern and works now.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `=` operator to assign a value in the file where the static variable is visible.

Comment: that doesn't work, for me it just sticks to its old value.

Comment: @findusl: It sounds like what you were trying to do is change a static variable from *another* file, where the variable is not visible. What "static" means in C is basically "this variable is only visible in this file." Static variables are pretty common in Objective-C — it's how, for example, singletons are commonly implemented. When other files need to set the variable, a setter function or method is provided.

Comment: But the static variable is visible and usable in the other file. Just can't be changed.

Comment: @findusl: I am very sure that is not the case with any mainstream compiler — that would violate the C standard. It's hard to say without seeing your code, but I'd guess you're creating a second, unrelated variable, rather than seeing the file's static variable. For example, if you have `static int x = 5;` in a header file, every file that imports that header would have a static variable named `x` that is unrelated to any other file's static variable named `x`.

Comment: Could be that that happens. Would explain the result since I wanted to change it for a different file.